# How to fetch object properties from selected object in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a list of `City` objects with `name` and `id` fields. I use Struts2 and I a have jsp page with a select tag.

```
<s:select label="Source city" 
          list="cities" 
          name="source"/>
```

Here is `Action` class

```
public class CalculationAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<City> cities;
    private DataAccessPerformer dao = new DataAccessPerformer();
    private String source;
    private int sourceId;

    public CalculationAction() {
        cities = new ArrayList<City>();
        // getting cities from database
        setCities(dao.getAllCities());
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

`City` class

```
public class City {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getCityName();
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

In this way I'm getting `source` field initialized, but I can't fetch `sourceId`.

I tried to change `source` field type to `City`, but I got `FieldError`

> Invalid field value for field "source".

How should I properly fetch the id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `id` to the value of the select tag you should use additional attributes

```jsp
<s:select label="Source city" 
          list="cities" 
          listKey="id"
          listValue="name"
          name="sourceId"/>
```

Comment: Now it works. I added attributes to select tag, but changed `listKey="idStringValue"`. I also changed type of `sourceId` to String and created `getIdStringVaule` method in `City` class.